# Is there a way to suppress / restrict logs getting executed ONLY from karate.exec or karate.fork?

Tags: karate

Trying to find a workaround for this issue

> 08:37:10.632 [Test worker] ERROR com.intuit.karate.Suite - <>
> unable to write report file(s):
> classpath:QA/ActivateLOB/activateLOB_gold.feature -
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

1. Changing the mode from DEBUG to INFO -> Memory issue got resolved but HTTP request and response is not shown in reports
   **`<logger name="com.intuit.karate" level="DEBUG"/>`**
2. Tried to increase the Maximum Heap Size to 2G and 3G as mentioned in https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/264, but that doesn't help

Comment: this sounds like an old version of karate that is not supported anymore. if you can replicate the problem following this process, the team will look at it

Comment: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue